# How can I typeset this letter in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I want to find the LaTeX symbol for the character shown in the attached image.

[image]

I have tried `\mathcal{J}`, `\jmath`, `\textctj`, `\mathscr{J}`, and `\mathfrak{J}`, but none of them worked.

Comment: Where did you get the image?  A pdf will contain font information that may hold some clues.

Comment: @Teepeemm
I copied from a book. I checked it and It cloud not help me...

Comment: Detexify (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) doesn't seem to recognize the symbol/font. Either that, or I'm really bad at drawing, which is very likely.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to access the "Euler" "math-script" symbols. One way to do so is to load the [mathalfa](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) package -- the spelling "mathalpha" is also valid -- with the option `scr=euler`.

[image]

[image]

Among font afficionados, Euler script letters (created by the late Hermann Zapf) are known for being almost perfectly upright. This in stark contrast to most other math-script letters, which tend to be moderately or even heavily sloped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=euler]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{J}$

$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLM}$

$\mathscr{NOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this answer received 40 upvotes within just the first 50 hours after I posted it. Many thanks, everybody!!

Comment: I am glad for you and for the precious contribute. In addendum I have sent you all